# Select right vector with template

Tags: c++, templates

I am following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422106/how-do-i-select-a-member-variable-with-a-type-parameter) in order to select the right container, but I am encountering problems.

I have a `selector` class that must push back into a vector of pointers, but the right one depends on its dimension (1 for vectors, 2 for matrices):

```
class selector
{
    struct formValues : std::vector<coolvector<double>*>, std::vector<coolmatrix<double>*> { };

    formValues maps;

public:

    selector() { };

    template<unsigned int formdim, typename F>
    void operator+=(const form<formdim, F> &f)
    {
        typedef typename form<formdim, F>::storage_type storage_type;

        typedef typename std::vector<storage_type*> pointer_type;

        // Push to the right vector
        formValues<pointer_type> &m = maps;

        m.push_back(f.storage.get());
    }        
};
```

The forms class have a dimension and a storage, again depending on the dimension, using shared pointers:

```
template <bool, class if_true, class if_false>
struct type_switch
{
    typedef if_false type;
};

template <class if_true, class if_false>
struct type_switch<true, if_true, if_false>
{
    typedef if_true type;
};

template <class T> class coolvector {};
template <class T> class coolmatrix {};

template<unsigned int formdim, typename F>
class form
{
public:
    form() = delete;

    form(const std::string &s) : type(s)
    {
        storage = std::make_shared<storage_type>();
    }

    std::string type;

    typedef typename type_switch<formdim == 1, coolvector<double>, coolmatrix<double>>::type storage_type;

    std::shared_ptr<storage_type> storage;
};

class oneform : public form<1, oneform>
{
public:
    oneform() = delete;

    oneform(const std::string &s) : form(s) { };

    double operator()(unsigned int i) { return i * 2; };
};

class twoform : public form<2, twoform>
{
public:
    twoform() = delete;

    twoform(const std::string &s) : form(s) { };

    double operator()(unsigned int i, unsigned int j) { return i * 2 + j * 20; };
};
```

The problem is that in the `selector::operator+=` I get this error:

```
main.cpp:77:19: error: expected unqualified-id
        formValues<pointer_type> &m = maps;
                  ^
```

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: `+=` should return `selector*` (`this`) instead of `void`?  .... `formValues` type !=  `formValues<pointer_type>` type?

Comment: I could return `selector&`, but it has no influence on the problem.

Comment: `type_switch` looks a lot like `std::conditional`.

Comment: Yes it is, it comes from far away!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`formValues` is not a template, so you can't write `formValues<pointer_type>`.

You appear to mean

```
pointer_type& m = maps;
```

to get the appropriate base class subobject of `maps`.