# Complexities of multiple inheritance of QObject for template type deduction

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, multiple-inheritance

## Background

I believe I have come up with a solution to the infamous problem of template signals and slot within Qt. For starters, I have defined an empty base `Message` class, whose sole purpose is to be inherited from and create concrete `TMessage` implementations. In Qt, while it is possible to connect a signal to a functor (as opposed to a Qt slot), a signal cannot be a template function, so my solution was to model the relation of the `Message` class as well, creating an abstract `Messenger` class, with a `void signal_Message(Message)` signal and a `template <typename T> void slot_T(TMessage<T>)`. I then came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422106/how-do-i-select-a-member-variable-with-a-type-parameter) and this question, and realized this was a much more maintanable solution, and I created essentially what is a bag of `Messenger`s. When using an unsupported type, the even code fails at compile time with a nice, readable error message:
`invalid initialization of reference of type Messenger<double>& from expression of type MessengerBag<int, char>`

## Problem

Consider we use 6 distinct types, `int`, `float`, `char`, `double`, some `enum`, and a `struct`. This yields a `sizeof` 96 bytes! However, given that the desired usage is for places with upwards of 50 user defined types, each with their own separately maintained containers of signals and slots, it looks as though my solution can perform the same task with around the same overhead, but next to none of the maintenance costs. Aside from the obvious benefits of no longer having to maintain 24 separate functions, possibly even more in the case of convoluted inheritance schemes, is there a downside to this approach? After doing some initial testing I found that The `MessengerBag` is essentially the opposite of a diamond pattern. Each destructor is called accordingly, so I see practically no disadvantages when compared to a composite structure, which would require another level of (what I consider to be needless and obfuscating) indirection. Qt essentially despises virtual inheritance, and disallows it in a class that directly inherits QObject: as such I cannot make Mock virtual as I would have preferred.

## Example

```
// Message.h
struct Message {};
template <typename T> struct TMessage {
    T t
};

// Messenger.h
struct Messenger : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    template <typename T> void slot_doSomethingWithMsg(const Message& msg){
        const auto& tmsg = static_cast<const TMessage<T>&>(msg);
        qDebug() << tmsg.t;
        // do something else... this is just example usage
    }
signals:
    void signal_sendMsg(const BaseMsg& msg);

// MessengerBag.h

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct MessengerBag : TMessenger<T>, MessengerBag<Args...>{};

template <typename T> struct MessengerBag<T> : TMessenger<T>{};

// Manager.h

MessengerBag<int, char> messengerBag;

Manager(){
    QObject::connect(static_cast<TMock<int>*>(messengerBag),
                     &Mock::signal_sendMsg, 
                     static_cast<TMock<int>*>(messengerBag),
                     &Mock::slot_doSomethingWithMsg<int>);

    QObject::connect(static_cast<TMock<char>*>(messengerBag),
                     &Mock::signal_sendMsg, 
                     static_cast<TMock<char>*>(messengerBag),
                     &Mock::slot_doSomethingWithMsg<char>);

template <typename T> void slot_sendMsg(const TMessage<T>& msg){
    TMessenger<T>& messenger = messengerBag;
    messenger.signal_sendMsg(msg);
}

// main.cpp

auto* manager = new Manager();

TMessage<int> imsg{5};
TMessage<char> cmsg{'f'};

manager->slot_sendMsg(imsg);
manager->slot_sendMsg(cmsg);
```

As expected, the above example prints 5 and 'f', thus subverting the issue with template signals and slots. However, I am having a little trouble seeing any possible issues in the future. One issue is of course that `QObject` is inaccessible because which `QObject` remains unknown, which a compositional solution could potentially mediate (make `TMessenger` delegate to `Messenger`, and `MessengerBag` inherit `QObject` in empty `Args` specialization. I hesitate to commit to this solution without first understanding its possible shortcomings. Also, feel free to leave comments on the code itself.

### tl;dr

Qt signals call functors, but signals cant be templates. Are there any downsides to having an object inherit multiple template classes that derived from `QObject`, in order to create template style signals by use of a base `Message`class? This `Message` is a parameter to the signal (so that the signal and template functor have the base version (after which the functor casts it to the correct type T). A struct will serve like a bag of these template classes, inheriting all of them in order to allow for upcasting to the right template class at any time.

Comment: @Zlytherin I've found that the longer my questions become, the less my questions become inundated with spam/people that really don't quite get the complexities of Qt. I'd rather have one really good, well-fitting answer than 15 terribly formatted ones that don't even come close to solving my problem and get my question locked. I'm sure you can understand this sentiment. I can add a tl;dr anyway, but I'm of the opinion it won't be to my benefit.

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand what you are doing but it sounds a little bit like something [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) might be useful for?

Comment: @Galik My hard requirement here is more so that I would like my connections to be distinct. i.e. int message and char message don't call the same function on the same object. So one function call for each type, because I have around 50 types in some cases and checking if they are convertible 50 times, maybe even multiple times a second seems like it goes downhill fast (think multiple classes communicating with multiple "bags"). I may be able to use the variant as a replacement for the base message class though.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a shot at this...

```
template<typename _Tb>
class _Ts : public _Tb 
{

public:
_Ts() {

// your connects

}

// any extensions to the qobject classes you are using
// note that you will need a common interface in your qobject subclasses... 
// meaning same named slots with different implementations 

};
```

Comment: Idk why template <typename _Tb>  won't add but thats above the class declaration.

Comment: -- meaning _Tb is the template, NOT _Ts.

Comment: Hey @Mike, I changed the formatting a bit so it's easier for me to read. Do you think you could come up with a sample implementation?

Comment: Is my understanding correct that you want an api that sends messages to a central dispatch from all over, but you want a common template to connect everything... including signals and slots with differe t parameters?

Comment: You get the gist of it yeah. I'd like to provide only one definition for a signal, and have all my slots receive (empty) base class parameter and do upcasting so that signals can be generic. My biggest problem I had when first trying to solve this was that signal_baseMsg(Message) connected to a slot of the same fashioned, wouldn't work because calling with TMessage<int> after connecting both TMessage<int> and TMessage<char> forced it to try and convert, which obviously failed. Does that make sense?

Comment: So i just got what you want to work i think...you must inheirt from template. Any type use use in the template place must have a common named signal. I connected to a global derivative of QObject (to avoid having to make a bunch of classes with the same named slot

Comment: And to answer how to do this with multiple parameter types... there are many ways to do so, but how i personally would to it is with a union. Have a union that can hold each type of variable, and assign to that variable for the object going into the signal and pull the required variable from the parameter in the slot.

Comment: As I suspected I'd still need to define each signal. I could probably do it in a macro though, which isn't too bad.

Comment: If you wanted too... unions can be used like templates in this sense. The catch tho is the slot object in the connect. You need a global/static/extern which supports the connection with union argument. In your case it would be your handler/manager. Have a global instance (perhaps singleton) to ug into your template subclass constructor connect statement. It actually sounds like an int we resting concept for qt app framework. Sorry i cant be of code oroviding help... like i said, im doing this from my phone.