# class auto create functions based on member name

Tags: c++, winapi

I Have a class that im reading from memory.

That has a bunch of linked lists.

Im trying to make my code smaller by somehow automaking the functions with templates.

I would like to be able to call it from its class menber function name with getFunction name

```
namespace
{
    class base
    {
    public:
        class SList<class Random1Obj> Random1ObjList;
        class SList<class Random2Obj> Random2ObjList;
        class SList<class Random3Obj> Random3ObjList;
        class SList<class Random4Obj> Random4ObjList;
    };


    std::vector<class Random1Obj*> getRandom1ObjList()
    {
        std::vector<class Random1Obj*> vRet;
        base This = *(base*)((DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("random.dll"));

        for (SLNode<Random1Obj>* node = This.Random1ObjList.Head(); node; node = node->Next())
        {
            vRet.push_back(node->Data());
        }

        return vRet;
    }

    std::vector<class Random2Obj*> getRandom2ObjList()
    {
        std::vector<class Random2Obj*> vRet;
        base This = *(base*)((DWORD)GetModuleHandleA("random.dll"));

        for (SLNode<Random2Obj>* node = This.Random2ObjList.Head(); node; node = node->Next())
        {
            vRet.push_back(node->Data());
        }

        return vRet;
    }

    .........
}
```

Comment: Have you actually used any of those functions? The cast from a module handle to `base*`, and the storing of pointers in a DLL look suspicious, to say the least.

Comment: What code are you trying to reduce? The code you write or the object code your compiler emits?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
namespace
{
    class base
    {
    public:
        class SList<class Random1Obj> Random1ObjList;
        class SList<class Random2Obj> Random2ObjList;
        class SList<class Random3Obj> Random3ObjList;
        class SList<class Random4Obj> Random4ObjList;
    };

    #define X(NAME, FUNNAME, DLL) std::vector<class NAME*> FUNNAME() \
    { \
        std::vector<class NAME*> vRet; \
        base This = *(base*)((DWORD)GetModuleHandleA(DLL)); \
        for (SLNode<NAME>* node = This.Random1ObjList.Head(); node; node = node->Next()) \
        { \
            vRet.push_back(node->Data()); \
        } \
        return vRet; \
    }

    X(Random1Obj, Random1ObjList, "random1.dll")
    X(Random2Obj, Random2ObjList, "random2.dll")
    X(Random3Obj, Random3ObjList, "random3.dll")
    X(Random4Obj, Random4ObjList, "random4.dll")

    #undef X
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, i thought there would of beena newer c++11 way without macro

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do via templates, you want to select a member variable at compile time based on a type. You can't really do this but you could instead use an envelope type instead of separate member variables for each SList. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422106/how-do-i-select-a-member-variable-with-a-type-parameter).

In your case it would be something like:

```
class base
{
public:

    struct Lists : 
        SList<Random1Obj>,
        SList<Random2Obj>,
        SList<Random3Obj>,
        SList<Random4Obj> {};

    Lists lists;
};

template<class T>
std::vector<T*> getRandomObjList()
{
    SList<T>& slist = This.lists;

    ...
}
```